# How to save a file to a directory with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this ruby code, that gets a xml file from the internet and save it. It saves it to the current dir, but a would like to save it to a specfik directory. How do I do that?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

base_url = 'SOME-URL'
extension = '.xml'
# the specfik dir
xml_dir = '/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/files/xmlfolder'

Nokogiri::HTML(open(base_url)).xpath("//a/@href").each do |src|  
  File.open(File.basename(src.value, File.extname(src.value)) + extension,'wb'){ |f| 
    f.write(open(src.value).read)
  }
  puts "Done with: #{base_url}"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having determined `xml_dir`, wrap your write in a Dir::chdir block, like this:

```
 Dir.chdir(xml_dir) do
   f.write # ...
 end
```

Alternatively construct an absolute path rather than than a partial path in your `File.open` call.

Comment: I tried that, but it still save it to the current dir. Can you show my the other option.

Comment: My wrong it workt, just that you have to put that block before File.open block. I would really like to see the option with the absolute path.

Comment: Go right ahead and form the absolute path and try it then. Right now you are forming a partial path in your File.open call, so you are writing into the "current directory".